# :focus effect not showing up on bootstrap radio button group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, radio-button

I created 2 Bootstrap group buttons since for my project's purpose, big buttons work better than a usual radio form. However, for some reason the `:checked` or `:focus` effect is not triggering here.

Adding `btn-secondary:focus{background-color:#8D69AD;}` made no difference as was recommended in all other similar issues. Perhaps the issue is that I have `input type="radio"` and button class is actually in the label?

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/GazoJm?editors=1111

extracted HTML for the 2 button groups here too:

```html
  <p>Select your year:</p>
  <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded">
      <input type="radio" name="year" id="junior" value="junior"> Junior
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="year" id="sophomore" value="sophomore"> Sophomore
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="year" id="senior" value="senior"> Senior
    </label>
  </div>


  <p>Select your path:</p>
  <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="artificer" value="artificer"> Artificer
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="healer" value="healer"> Healer
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="crypto" value="crypto"> Cryptozoologist
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="guardian" value="guardian"> Guardian
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="cursebreaker" value="cursebreaker"> Curse Breaker
    </label>
  </div>

  <span id="classResult"> </span>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Buttons as checkboxes is a feature of Bootstrap requiring their JavaScript library to work as intended. It is not possible to do this in CSS properly as it would either require a parent selector or the :has selector as the checked property of the DOM is only available from CSS on the input element itself but not on its parent which is a button. A simple fix for your application would be to add the Bootstrap JavaScript library:

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Popper.js should not be required. You could also use the slim build of jQuery as the Bootstrap homepage recommends.

```js
//function to display timetable according to user choices in year/path
//currently only Junior choices
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
        //making chosen radio options to variables
        var $year = $('input[name="year"]:checked');
        var $path = $('input[name="path"]:checked');
        //logic
        if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "artificer") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior artificer timetable!");
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "cursebreaker") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior cursebreaker timetable!");
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "crypto") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior crypto timetable!");
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "healer") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior healer timetable!");
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "guardian") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior guardian timetable!");
        } 
    });
});
```

```css
btn-secondary:focus{
  background-color:#8D69AD;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <br>

  <p>Select your year:</p>
  <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded">
      <input type="radio" name="year" id="junior" value="junior"> Junior
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="year" id="sophomore" value="sophomore"> Sophomore
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="year" id="senior" value="senior"> Senior
    </label>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  <p>Select your path:</p>
  <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="artificer" value="artificer"> Artificer
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="healer" value="healer"> Healer
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="crypto" value="crypto"> Cryptozoologist
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="guardian" value="guardian"> Guardian
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-1">
      <input type="radio" name="path" id="cursebreaker" value="cursebreaker"> Curse Breaker
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <span id="classResult"> </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Once again, Lukas, you've saved my day. Thank you so much! Captain America has nothing on you ;) 
(*goes back to code her tiny test project for the LARP nerds*